# How to detect DVD drive letter via BATCH file in MS WIndows 7?

Tags: windows-7, script, batch-file

How to detect DVD drive letter via BATCH file in MS WIndows 7?

I mean, I need to know that DVD  could have assigned letter D or E...

Is there any script to do  it?

Answer (score 2):

#### I need to know that DVD could have assigned letter D or E

`wmic` will give you this information.

Example output:

```
F:\test>wmic logicaldisk get deviceid, drivetype
DeviceID  DriveType
C:        3
D:        5
E:        2
F:        3
```

Notes:

```
DriveType   Meaning
 1          No root directory
 2          Removable drive
 3          Local hard disk
 4          Network disk
 5          Compact disk
 6          RAM disk
```

The following batch file will output the drive letter of your DVD/CD drive (GetCD.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, drivetype') do (
  if [%%j]==[5] echo %%i
  )
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>GetCD
D:

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.
  Example output:

Notes:

Answer (score 0):

ok. I found solution using this code

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
cls
echo Your %~d0 drive.
cd %~d0
dir
cd temp
pause
```

Comment: If you used this code, then the batch file must be on the DVD or CD drive...

Answer (score 0):

I found another option, looking for a predefined file.

---

> for %%i in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S Y Z) do (
>
> ```
> if exist %%i:\sources\boot.wim call :MEDIA %%i
> ```
>
> )
>
> :MEDIA
>
> set DRIVE=%1:\
>
> echo set DRIVE=%1:\

Answer (score 0):

- **[commandline](/questions/tagged/commandline)**

```bash
for /f eol^=^/^ ^usebackq^ ^tokens^=4*^ ^delims^=^<^> %# in =;(` wmic.exe logicaldisk where drivetype^=5 get deviceid /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"`);= do @for /f eol^=^/^ ^usebackq^ ^tokens^=4*^ ^delims^=^<^> %@ in =;(`wmic.exe cdrom get volumename /format:xml ^| find "VALUE" `);= do @echo/DeviceID=%# VolumeName=%@
```

---

- **[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)**

```bash
echo off

for /f eol^=^/^ ^usebackq^ ^tokens^=4*^ ^delims^=^<^> %%# in =;(`
     wmic.exe logicaldisk where drivetype^=5 get deviceid /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
    `);= do for /f eol^=^/^ ^usebackq^ ^tokens^=4*^ ^delims^=^<^> %%@ in =;(`
         wmic.exe cdrom get volumename /format:xml ^| find "VALUE" ^| more
        `);= do echo/DeviceID=%%# VolumeName=%%@
```

- Results/Outputs:

```
DeviceID=D: VolumeName=FINDING_NEMO
```

---